# LDAP search Delphi

Tags: delphi, ldap

I'm trying to get an name on LDAP data base searching with an identification number. I've got this on linux using this query:

```
 ldapsearch -x -v -w *username* -D uid=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx -b ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  "uid=xxxxxxxxx" cn
```

With this I can get the cn (name) of the uid xxxxx. I want something like that on Delphi 2007.

I was searching, but a lot is just trying to connect or validate something, and I don't understand.

I downloaded the library ActiveDs_TLB.pas, but don't know how to use it correctly. If someone could help me pasting the code or something like that it will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow isn't a place to ask people to do homework for you. Contact the library's vendor for questions in its implementation. Or, if it's related to Delphi programming, then include relevant code that we can use to recreate your issue.

Comment: This is a not so easy topic. You can use the ADHelper.pas unit from [here](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/Delphi/).

Comment: Ok Jerry Dodge, I've ask here because I have already tried and found nothing. Tnks, whosrdaddy, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches and download some libraries I found the answer. I made this basic function for tests and help who needs.

Sorry about this question here, but I hope it helps someone one day.

```
    procedure TForm1.OnClick2(Sender: TObject);
    var
      ldap: TLDAPsend;
      l: TStringList;
      host, username, psswd, base, cpf, result : string;
    begin
      ldap     := TLDAPsend.Create;
      l        := TStringList.Create;
      host     := teHost.text;
      username := teUser.text;
      psswd    := tePsswd.text;
      base     := teBase.text; //The base that you want to make the research.
      cpf      := teCpf.text;
      result   := '';
      try
        ldap.TargetHost := host; //like an IP. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    //next line is the key to getting AD authentication working
        ldap.UserName   := username; //like 'uid=_user_,ou=blabla,ou=blabla,ou=blabla,dc=bla,dc=bla,dc=bla'
        ldap.Password   := psswd;
        ldap.Login;
        Label1.Caption  := 'Logged...';
        ldap.BindSasl; // BindSasl have more security than Bind.
        Label1.caption  := 'Bind...';
        l.Add('cn'); //I want just the name, so search the 'cn'. If want more just add.
        ldap.Search(base, False, 'uid=' + cpf, l); //search with the CPF (an kind of documentation number)
        Label1.Caption  := 'Success !';
{The next line have a function "getLastLine" cause the LDAPResult print something like this:
Results: 1

Result: 0
  Object: uid=xxxxxxxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx
  Attribute: cn
    Fulano Ciclano de Tal
}
        result          := getLastLine(LDAPResultdump(ldap.SearchResult), #$D#$A);
        if (result <> '') and (result<> 'Results: 0') then
        begin
          teName.visible := true;
          teName.text    := result;
        end
        else
        begin
          Label1.Caption := 'No Result...';
          teName.Visible := false;
        end;
        ldap.Logout;
      finally
        ldap.Free;
        l.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

PS: This will need some libraries, the main is "ldapsend", and other like asn1util and blcksock. All may be found on synapse pack. Some of the libraries have bugs, but just remove that.